ASP NET - tinyMCE editor - Error 400 bad request
I am develeping web application where is in one form used tinyMCE editor. Users of the application uses this tinyMCE input field for saving screenshots and notes. That is fact and it cannot be easily undone.
Problem is that when someone pastes to big screeshot or too many or something, application doesn't save it on submit but error 400 bad request is given. Also when i add some extra input into  another input field, it works. It means it must be somehow limitation of one single input field.
I tried to come to to top limit where it still works and it is something close to 4 000 000 characters - which might be much more bytes.
I already tried to search soem limits of html input field and tinyMCE limits but found nothing helpful.
I also tried to increase form limit in startup of ASPNET app:
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
   //Set the limit 
   options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = limit;  
});

Does anybody know what might be causing it?
EDIT:
I laready tried following app configuration:
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
   // Set the limit to 128 MB
   options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 134217728;
});

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
   // Set the limit to 128 MB
   options.MaxRequestBodySize = 134217728;
});

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
   // Set the limit to 128 MB
   serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 134217728;
});

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => 
{
   //  Set the limit to 128 MB
   options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 134217728;
});


try adding this code in your program.cs file: `builder.Services.Configure(options =>
{
options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800; // 50 MB
});
builder.Services.Configure(options =>
{
options.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; // 50 MB
});
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; // 50 MB
});`

@JalpaPanchal  Althought the app is already in .NET 6, it was migrated from .NET 5 and it uses older configuration - so it uses IHostBuilder but not WebApplicationBuilder. But I tried the configurating MaxRequestBodySize and it did not helped. I might try reimplement configuration with WebApplicationBuilder.

@JalpaPanchal I already rewrited app and builder configuration so I was able to try configure all what you suggested, but nothing helped.

Could you share your updated code? what is the datatype in the database for the column. services. Configure<FormOptions>(options => {             options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800; // 50 MB         });         services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>         {             options.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; // 50 MB         });         services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>         {             options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; // 50 MB         });

@JalpaPanchal I tried configurations that you suggested (see EDIT section). Datatype in DB is CLOB but I think that is absolutely not important here, because the program does not fall with any exception from DB but it gives http 400 bad request error

SOLUTION
I did not give up googling and find that I can setup size of individual form value:
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
   // Set the limit to 128 MB
   options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 134217728;
   options.ValueLengthLimit = 134217728;
});

The second line of the options settings solves the problem.
I found the solution on stack overflow as well and I am surprised i did not see it first time I was trying to find the answer.
see: stackoverflow solution
